# Android code to verify my login e-mail

Tags: android, sqlite, session, authentication, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create an android application in which I've to verify the user's email address by sending a verification code and re-directing the user to enter the code in the mobile application.

In this case, can you please explain how I can maintain a record that the user has verified his mail id. The problem what I'm facing is that when I store these details in Shared Preferences, the details get erased when the user exits the application. Therefore user is prompted to enter the verification code many times

Also whenever the user comes out of the my application, the user is automatically logged out. I'm storing the user details in Shared Preferences. Therefore whenever the application is started it asks for a login. Can you please explain how I can make the user stay logged-in until the user he himself opts to log-out.

Is there any way I can achieve these details without using Sqlite database???

Comment: you can just save verification code based on user then check this when user login again.

Comment: This part of your question is not possible `when I store these details in Shared Preferences, the details get erased when the user exits the application`. This is why SharedPreferences exists in the first place

Comment: for user stay logged in you have to just take boolean flag when you login that time you have to set it true and at the time of logout set it false then check everytime when splash activty called if flag is true then call your main activity else login activity

Comment: do you cleared the SharedPreferences when exiting from application? Because SharedPreferences data cleared only when you cleared in code or manually from Apps in device settings, they don't erase  automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Save the status in cache file. For that 

Create InternalStorage.java

```
public final class InternalStorage{

        private InternalStorage() {}

        public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object) throws IOException {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(object);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }

        public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) throws IOException,
                ClassNotFoundException {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Object object = ois.readObject();
            return object;
        }
    }
```

Now After the verification for the first time, create a file with status in cache

```
try {
    // Save the status like verified 
    InternalStorage.writeObject(this, "cache_fileName", "verified");

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

And in the MainActivity's OnCreate Method, check for the cache file value, If the file has value = "verified", then start the activity to which you want to go

```
/*Check For status From Cache File*/
try {
    // Retrieve the file value
    verify= (String) InternalStorage.readObject(this, "cache_fileName");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
}
try{
    if(verify.equals("verified")){
        startActivity("specify_your_activity");
    }
}catch (NullPointerException e){

}
```

And Put this in AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```